# camera black out issue on screen?

Tags: iphone

I am working on virtual binocular in iphone.I made a application for both iphone and ipad. Getting  issue regarding camera black out sceen. Actually, when first time application has load on the iphone its call viewdidload method after that it will call viewwillappear and then viewdidappear.But when I working on my application its work properly but during that duration if i open the other application and reopen again my application it gave me black screen on camera. it simply means that it didnot load the application